# Proof of Inequality $x(1-e^{-1/x})\geq (1-e^{-x})$ for $0\leq x\leq1$

Tags: inequality

I would like to prove the inequality $x(1-e^{-1/x})\geq (1-e^{-x})$ for $0\leq x\leq1$. I have verified the inequality numerically, and it appears to hold true.

It is simple to prove $x\geq (1-e^{-x})$, but the one I posted is unclear to me. I would greatly appreciate any suggestions or alternative methods for proving this inequality.

Answer (score 1):

It is not hard to show that
$$1-e^{-1/x} \geq 1-e^{-1}x$$
and
$$\frac{1-e^{-x}}{x} \leq 1-e^{-1}x$$
for $x\in(0,1)$. Then
$$x\left(1-e^{-1/x}\right) - \left(1-e^{-x}\right) \geq x(1-e^{-1}x) - x(1-e^{-1}x) = 0 \, .$$

Comment: This is clever! Thanks